# Return an iterator to boost multiintex container as a std::set<>::iterator

Tags: boost, boost-multi-index, stdset

The documentation for Boost multiindex containers seem to indicate that I can use it as a set after declaring an index to iterate over. So I was wondering if it is possible to hide the boost implementation and return an iterator masqueraded as an iterator to an `std::set`

Ex: Header

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    Employee, 
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique<
            composite_key<
                Employee,
                member<Employee, int, &Employee::id>,
                member<Employee, int, &Employee::salary>
            >
        >
    > > EmployeeSet;
const std::set<Employee>::iterator getEmployees();

static EmployeeSet employeeSet;
```

Test.cc:

```
const std::set<Test::Employee>::iterator getEmployees(){
    std::pair<EmployeeSet::iterator, EmployeeSet::iterator> by_id =
    employeeSet.equal_range(id);
    return by_id.first;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? and How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. The `EmployeeSet` you have defined works like a `std::set` (a `std::multiset`, actually), but it is not one. The `iterator` types of these unrelated containers are different and you can't pass one as the other.

Maybe you can reconsider why you need to pass an `iterator` to an index of a `multi_index_container` as a `std::set::iterator`.